# Select Distinct on a substring of a column using the CharIndex function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have fullName column with concatenated first name and last names, separated by a '-'. 
I am trying to select distinct first names and do a count(*) to see how many Toms, Janes, Harry's, etc... exist.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(fullName, CHARINDEX('-',fullName,0)-1) as firstName, count(*) as numOfNames
FROM tblFullNames
GROUP BY fullName
```

When I run the above, I get a proper list of the first names but I get a "1" as the result for number of names for every entry, even though I know there are multiple Tom's, Jane's, etc...

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make Gordon's first point explicit, where he says "you can repeat the expression", he means this:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(fullName, CHARINDEX('-',fullName,0)-1) as firstName, 
  count(*) as numOfNames
FROM 
  tblFullNames
GROUP BY 
  LEFT(fullName, CHARINDEX('-',fullName,0)-1)
```

You don't need `DISTINCT` if you're using a `GROUP BY`. `DISTINCT` just creates a `GROUP BY` clause in the background.

If your table is big enough for performance to be a consideration, Gordon's `CROSS APPLY` will out perform this.

And since we're talking about names, I'm sort of required to suggest you read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by the fullname.  You can repeat the expression . . . or use `cross apply`:

```
 SELECT v.firstName, count(*) as numOfNames
FROM tblFullNames fn CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (LEFT(fn.fullName, CHARINDEX('-', fn.fullName, 0) - 1)
             )
     ) v(firstName)
GROUP BY v.firstName;
```